# Python: time stretch wave files - comparison between three methods

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, scikit-image, librosa, data-augmentation

I'm doing some data augmentation on a speech dataset, and I want to stretch/squeeze each audio file in the time domain.

I found the following three ways to do that, but I'm not sure which one is the best or more optimized way:

```
dimension = int(len(signal) * speed)
res = librosa.effects.time_stretch(signal, speed)
res = cv2.resize(signal, (1, dimension)).squeeze()
res = skimage.transform.resize(signal, (dimension, 1)).squeeze()
```

However, I found that `librosa.effects.time_stretch` adds unwanted echo (or something like that) to the signal.

So, my question is: What are the main differences between these three ways? And is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### librosa.effects.time_stretch(signal, speed) ([docs](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.effects.time_stretch.html))

In essence, this approach transforms the signal using `stft` ([short time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)), stretches it using a [phase vocoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder) and uses the inverse `stft` to reconstruct the time domain signal. Typically, when doing it this way, one introduces a little bit of "phasiness", i.e. a metallic clang, because the phase cannot be reconstructed 100%. That's probably what you've identified as "echo."

Note that while this approach effectively stretches audio in the time domain (i.e., the input is in the time domain as well as the output), the work is actually being done in the frequency domain.

### cv2.resize(signal, (1, dimension)).squeeze() ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)))

All this approach does is interpolating the given signal using [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation). This approach is suitable for images, but strikes me as unsuitable for audio signals. Have you listened to the result? Does it sound at all like the original signal only faster/slower? I would assume not only the tempo changes, but also the frequency and perhaps other effects.

### skimage.transform.resize(signal, (dimension, 1)).squeeze() ([docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize))

Again, this is meant for images, not sound. Additionally to the interpolation ([spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) with the order `1` by default), this function also does anti-aliasing for images. Note that this has *nothing* to do with avoiding audio aliasing effects ([Nyqist/Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency#Aliasing)), therefore you should probably turn that off by passing `anti_aliasing=False`. Again, I would assume that the results may not be exactly what you want (changing frequencies, other artifacts).

### What to do?

IMO, you have several options.

1. If what you feed into your ML algorithms ends up being something like a Mel spectrogram, you could simply treat it as image and stretch it using the skimage or opencv approach. Frequency ranges would be preserved. I have successfully used this kind of approach in [this music tempo estimation paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hendrik_Schreiber/publication/328028453_A_Single-Step_Approach_to_Musical_Tempo_Estimation_Using_a_Convolutional_Neural_Network/links/5bb3933692851ca9ed349cf7/A-Single-Step-Approach-to-Musical-Tempo-Estimation-Using-a-Convolutional-Neural-Network.pdf).
2. Use a better time_stretch library, e.g. [rubberband](https://pyrubberband.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pyrubberband.pyrb.time_stretch.html#pyrubberband.pyrb.time_stretch). librosa is great, but its current time scale modification (TSM) algorithm is not state of the art. For a review of TSM algorithms, see for example [this article](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/6/2/57/pdf).
3. Ignore the fact that the frequency changes and simply add 0 samples on a regular basis to the signal or drop samples on a regular basis from the signal (much like your image interpolation does). If you don't stretch too far it may still work for data augmentation purposes. After all the word content is not changed, if the audio content has higher or lower frequencies.
4. Resample the signal to another sampling frequency, e.g. `44100 Hz -> 43000 Hz` or `44100 Hz -> 46000 Hz` using a library like [resampy](https://github.com/bmcfee/resampy) and then *pretend* that it's still 44100 Hz. This still change the frequencies, but at least you get the benefit that resampy does proper filtering of the result so that you avoid the aforementioned [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency#Aliasing), which otherwise occurs.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. However, I'm using Windows 10 OS, and I have python 3.6 on it, and I'm trying to install rubberband using the command `pip install rubberband`, but it raises the following error: "Failed building wheel for rubberband", and I can't use Python 3.5 in my project, so do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no actual experience with rubberband. It simply has a very good reputation, which is why I recommended it. Perhaps raise an issue on https://github.com/bmcfee/pyrubberband/issues?