# Is it possible to stretch a numpy array using a fraction

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to stretch raw audio using numpy to use it pygame, is there a way to do this?

I've tried using numpy.repeat() which works really well but I'm limited to whole number multiplication. Is there a way do stretch [[1 2], [3 2], [5 1], [2 -1]] to 1.5 times is length for example.

Here's some basic code for you to work with. B64LZ_data contains raw signed 8bit samples.

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import base64
import lzma

B64LZ_data = b'/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L+Wj4A6XCrRdAABovfwPV/G15vX8madXHfY\
m+Pyyka5Wp9jKFPlDovkuujKnrbEEArahOFuCGNELB7kqw6tGi6Lw/Z43fMuPuMlJDFQcTCfbLrED+\
slA7MMyNijXyRsgaWKQn2KTO85hCcC1YQf2n1yPhT4WOgB06BWw0t144ks98HfNYK4d09VYozGQ8PO\
C0OuWadtH7rpbZi1sqpQ4sbkvpvZvMyd7oiE9PWcqJU2Bj9Rswcnx1aNvkDPcrr1uwq+stPFfjnGTu\
L9O67E76/gIQvVXeJY7Tc4vpHYOHdE/RgYBYheeNxLhulSKjkcTOygS+emvL72ZHb3jsyvOZEPN9BV\
BA28DEj4BNXuqkgzeM4BcIUqAXyu464N1cpVJqpmwA32r1ZdzlJL9YUggioLGqZAPEXSiHhZGtn8tv\
ZGhBfeLorTNUWHFi9bALjui2xo0WC3fNwSgBxAclNJxa3H7JTPG+sY0CwvfmVJ2ttkt2vGbdr9LWJ2\
NIQwFzcFif9J6YZxn9jYvC1iLpcPdwBvvon+67wWBIL37OfQtDP5S1lgVVUYdjS9nVLH6FPv+DfLq/\
p8vOqfL1Ls/BseD18H0gzeptip3be8vvJhRcKJqIuGUxHqhkg9o45FS3+MoOA7NYHhQbxuA2bkP3E3\
xTkTsCjlYk/Fw7LuYgwSfRZZA+9JDTtUxFqOY++xjk2jY2x3zOVNIXu00xdG5FRB9Ee+n+6jPFQ9uv\
8py/kkhOhvN6DSbwJcNB/iITXonS0Q0QaNhsKrQ2glkuR+zv/hBL93mu677cslkrxofoHRBo3ys5fw\
QU3rju3VdIHd5lpoHMyGoj9jK7mV5wW120D3KrXu7oUUL0qH94vGQ2rVeT5fe36KaIlsGStHkApt1g\
Oc0WSMYoigz+POB3JCaL7myyQPsKDprbi6d1YD4ULch+xRGlxfryB/fUXc0uviaIPMxa7VIt0pgc4B\
1rqA2zE8i7hpiF3dhLSlqpcPed4LWPAzILLxOYOfFzROnVZFzxIxRJ++CyUemiHcRYEdJZgQL7fchN\
66bzT1Ua6E6aN3ME8wUpCPtjTv0JXFE1ErUtkE4vfqYzpJogYyuBp5T1tlhmNlI9dZPouEx7B5rCU4\
o063BGVvzhKOFQlyCOVZcD8YHN/dStAfEuWjauOeExVHIlQjsRn606AHXMMWf/eP3pcMEAlC4Rc73+\
ASFDHtK3+991cKaIpY4LmtfCl25FfZ9jL3/X1Tp+jl45PQYTx/3qJ660oAc45uHJquBj7c5qf1oZub\
5QfiC/ni10duN/UNMpLgfOAubWgcZpSSuS7biVxlkbFqRjJY9x2PtKWHfOu2gvTSVc+8akgTVJ3TXR\
8dUfN+WGaGJrq9iN7f2lIV7vBaRx53Q9Nb+66Gc8RgTvsOPZ+8g8OKEtQoznuBczC0zzHJs0ajLEaL\
ETz+rI2ikzyeqTFCUp74rFmwjzK/A1ghhHeLYOGqu3+N8TtA9PtlDKZTcxKbUf046AEJbfhxNBojPG\
Cj1jNBk7wx/tWmFZ8feqQM4sVHH4GIOCqoMxf96swfElvnq5jHjQO0IO2wrnK0kcfIjyeNSMvunEH0\
Fwf2lKbuC/MIqPEUbDiD6wBRF7ubdMibiaDLbqjngDawkOyHcoRw+rb+D2Y0gf3PlZZR3A0gQHaWf5\
6ScFZ1/j57tts0Ero9CxFM8PwV8Iv8udKCWFlOB7Y84mVdwwoX26IsnoLTU+NBGUpqTzhdZlPAbikH\
7iJgtCohfxIa9XlCIQqzBvwDRVDls5qbGWQz0zz6D+3IXIIEsl9Eq8OlIIp6v4ZCcCLafbEfUqBT+x\
Q3QQK+FRAYjIhHmSmf2AOxU3C5GWWVS26EHSVBBgJhyad1eiqFiK2lHqZalzE0gI8g4qCykWhZHtNn\
TcqYkp4FRoKyVIQEQLRwkqgKJ5XIm5iCfPIFuoSsP1VkuON5X4axz87KU2TriGPJOdLJcynFLRxGKD\
I0WCtsU+074LTyzBsizmH+eVvzk/Lh73SZrJSrjYgOADO7CLbQBStglOX9pdFxBAqGB/ZCVAAFPrlH\
04QVX4vzEl+dub2j2TRxrsnctgaVG83iIHlFPoQ7BE6ZdBHbBBfJDH/0ooxR8Z1VlvfdOgeLxBD62d\
N78IwAJMU7cdcc2EYBpTzau9fFeG/HkSVEo6swNj4ghgCv9c6Kw03uxePWEl8pLY4Gldt2ubccMHh1\
8lS8oaFeeuottn4i4vbBqjRsqQUCRphwmMG0ORt1Ptn/UqipnBZGuJ76tEwBHbDVV8LCd8EGEKT74a\
81lSLeUL27dcdBtRpNhS7IL7GQsnNH66nWbpMVuCNQBuqHzmwMuzLOaMHWUgaznkbF2d4zxKOksP0v\
o7wdIneKZfB3MG+bdbS14vTdNMh3RvONvEY+R71ZFT9K7w0thw03m2NYk7pS/ln95cYMAIsaHA1Quz\
To5w6RurFb05PUrnfxzzdBoYwJGWXSZ1RZ7tdmUWVOQ2b/U7kYhr0SmcgmfNAvKDHQfVoNyMmCNNK8\
kZP89SDLA1A+twqeH4yrDHw4sJXkY7xnCK68nQ3uISN1ijGKABnW9sgb0qrL52rLAFy4PHT6x163Rc\
8qpBSBCJxkeeJ49wuRnWU6AH4y4kFxamkdCtPCHePUnMg/WdTy8GJXlX4ylMG4TlcQsn8zoHuNQ91O\
OPeXxOTIpsyAXlWn932Bhw2hsE+SHVCXw4Nn1Zl4J6hH9S97XpBNHZHwEzEIH+qLxkEKrJYS1hiPED\
uUUcJcM3hwIU3DopKYaghw+P13W/C4QLscLQVNCDKS1XL0/ooVWwOICcvdzxW10YZx8m0K82s3cutT\
IaxrLsBRR7XGoAjDvUbloLhHu3otqqCFKT4mQaVsGBeFLe8IlmLoD0JY7SWbwGlA5CRD4OpNzogoFG\
I/bQxdsUavwFF8eeDtkpHd6uwj3X/etFirilqesedJwF995+ovorgwqyUIvRRDg3yiaXTHwgbKvZko\
5N9coUjdQMy+GwCjiGu7gcRn9GFt/E9m5a8UFWkU0jLeqS4FPz96ELhtlinnFo6szw5yRs88YajLBY\
sxpf6pi/sAXHptRiMERWZENnW1XN/YmfvmkyunvYEVxS2kLApUTWMRrp2kKkR2GOX/HPVuSKZrEtzV\
5tR1taEs3CS3uUXIC0YXEaNhkm7wL2V1nqXYubd+O3jJF2KWgMRFnY31Z1RnL7icLXRd8eoA0nxoFG\
L3BzX8TT1XMyheJJexpqqCeBDs/Mnfmbcto+YA1UMt2kZu8cnEAQMhNl7zCy08OMEQkNum7XWRGnpZ\
7FmdhKvid2iWhnBS+MjmGuRNJGgFggKvn6ITR5wY9xI/5AMXZtkzLDo1zhxrgeySrKxZc7Pnbf22sb\
CNlAdRGLGDUwel9GOMridu8+761jMMD9pIz3mNv99j9p8xZ/mf5ic7fh1LcQUKuHN5KASnt5Tr6gQI\
fJr2CmkC5zpcb+juA3wkEHJfMkhwjM39G2Ukm7wTYt2bvSfTX5+KZyMTZdI1P/0SBRX37mOCLVEgt+\
p1pKnxpQs65No3ovp2fA9CWp3yHO7xOZ6nvwtaLWxkrQy/0b2RRK5NS4lxnTFMKgBtPxtQhs0QVF9I\
hGsWKnMta2iw7RfVzlhmnIvGjFJdhX2wj1kvNfsE4AAAAHwYw0L6Bdi8AAdAVmB0AAGgpYRWxxGf7A\
gAAAAAEWVo='

data = lzma.decompress(base64.b64decode(B64LZ_data))

ln = len(data)

# turn bytes into a 2-channel data stream
stereo = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int8).reshape(ln // 2, 2)
# this works really well but can only multiply with whole numbers
stretched = np.repeat(stereo, 5, axis=0) # stretch x5

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, size=-8)
pygame.init()

sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(stretched)

while True:
    sound.play()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(0.5)
```

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: What if the array length is not even? Like 7 the 1.5 length is 10.5

Comment: What do you mean by stretch? You can probably slice the array to `stereo[:len(arr)//2]` to get partial audio and then add it to the `repeated array`. I still however think that using an audio editing program would be better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: time stretch wave files - comparison between three methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867659/python-time-stretch-wave-files-comparison-between-three-methods)

Comment: @DaniMesejo So that means some of the data is stretched but other bits are left out. So for instance [1, 2, 3, 4] * 1.25 might be [1, 2, 3, 3, 4], or * 1.5 might be [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4] etc

Comment: @kinshukdua I can't use audio software because I'm editing audio on the fly to play music and each sample has to be a different pitch

Comment: @sehan2 If I can just use numpy that would be great, if not then I'll have to consider different options thanks